# Determining Symmetries Using Canonical Coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to determine the symmetries for the solutions to $\ddot{y} = 0$ where $y=y(x)$.

I have determined the 8 vectors and the Lie Algebras.

I have determined the canonical coordinates $(r,s)$ and now need to determine $\frac{ds}{dr}$ for each of my vectors.

In Bluman & Anco, this is defined as:
$$
\frac{ds}{dr} = \frac{s_x + s_y y'}{r_x + r_y y'}
$$

For one of my vectors I have:
\begin{align*}
s = & \frac{-1}{x} & & r=\frac{y}{x}\\
\end{align*}

I am calculating:
\begin{align*}
\frac{ds}{dr} = & \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}+0}{\frac{-y}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}y'}\\
  = & \frac{1}{x^2}\left(\frac{x^2}{-y+xy'}\right)\\
  = & \frac{1}{-xr + xy'}\\
  = & \frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{1}{y'-r}\right)\\
  = & \frac{s}{r-y'}\\ 
\end{align*}

I can now solve for $s$ by:

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{s}ds = & \frac{1}{\left( r - y' \right) } dr\\
\ln s = & \ln \left( r- y' \right) \\
s = & r - y'
\end{align*}

**NB** I want the simplest solution and so am omitting the constant.

I rearrange and substitute $s(x,y)$ and $r(x,y)$ to find $y$:

\begin{align*}
y' = & r - s\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = & \frac{y}{x} + \frac{1}{x}\\
\frac{1}{y+1}dy = & \frac{1}{x}dx \\
\ln \left( y + 1 \right ) = & \ln x\\
y = & x - 1\\
\end{align*}

Is this correct?

Now my second vector is: 
$ X_2 = y \partial x $

when $\eta = 0$ we set $r = x$
Now the formula to determine $s$ is the same and we get $ s = \ln y $

When I try to find $\frac{ds}{dr}$ as above, I get
$$
\frac{ds}{dr} = \frac{y'}{y}
$$

In trying to solve for $y$ I have the following:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y \ln y}{x}\\
\\
\frac{1}{y \ln y} dy = & \frac{1}{x} dx \\
\\
\ln \left( \ln y \right) = & \ln x \\
\\
\ln y = & x \\
\\
y = e^x \\
\end{align*}

Something is obviously wrong in what I am doing as the solution should be linear.

I think the fact that $ r = x $ and thus $y = y(r) $ comes into play, I just don't know how.

Please help.

Thanks